# Render each array Index as each table in React

Tags: reactjs

I have data like this.

```
products: [
  {b: "brand1", N: "N1", M: "M1", B: "B1", S: "y1", O: "y1", A: "y1", D: "y1"},
  {b: "brand2", N: "N2", M: "M2", B: "B2", S: "y2", O: "y2", A: "y2", D: "y2"},
  {b: "brand3", N: "N3", M: "M3", B: "B3", S: "y3", O: "y3", A: "y3", D: "y3"},
  {b: "brand4", N: "N4", M: "M4", B: "B4", S: "y4", O: "y4", A: "y4", D: "y4"},
  ]
```

I need to display each index of the products array into each table.

I have tried like this but it is displaying all the arrays indices in single table

```
Products.map(row => (
             <tr key={ row.key } >
              <td >{ row.key }</td>
              { productid.map(product => (
                  <td key={ product }>{ row[product].toString() }</td>
              ))}
          </tr>
      ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
products.map((row, index) => (
  <table key={index}>
  <tr>
    <th>
      {Object.keys(row).map(item => (
        <td>{item}</td>
      ))}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      {Object.keys(row).map(item => (
        <td>{row[item]}</td>
      ))}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

));

You can also refer the codesandbox I created for this.https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-6uljz

Comment: It will also display entire products array data into single table, but i need to display it as each array index to each table

Comment: So if there are n products in the array, there should be n tables. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, for each product in the in the array i need each table.

Comment: No it is displaying all data in the same table

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated to code also refer the codesandbox I created for this.